# Segmentation Fault при запуске программы

Tags: c++, unix

Пытаюсь выполнить C++ код на своей Debian-машине. Использую GCC-компилятор. Он мой код компилирует без ошибок и предупреждений, но в момент запуска я получаю ошибку **Segmentation fault**. Погуглил эту проблему, и нашёл кое-что. Предлагают выполнить дебаг программы через GDB. Что я сделал:

```
gcc /путь_к_программе -g
gdb ./a.out
run
backtrace
```

В итоге дебаггер указал мне, что ошибка вот в этом участке кода:

```
while(fgets(strLine, 256, list_fd) != NULL)
    {
            ParseResolverLine(strLine, iLine);
            iLine++;
    }
```

Выдача самого дебаггера:

```
#0  _IO_fgets (buf=0x607010 "", n=256, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:50
#1  0x000000000040185f in main (argc=6, argv=0x7fffffffec68)
```

Собственно, не понимаю, где именно в указанном мною участке кода проявляется сегментация памяти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `list_fd` равен `NULL` (`fp=0x0` в отладчике). Проверьте, что файл открылся, если что-то не получается `fopen()` возвращает `NULL`.